# How can I add Deno autocompletions to an Elvish shell?

Tags: shell

I'm trying out both Deno and Elvish and would like to use "Shell Autocomplete" as described [here](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/setup_your_environment). It tells how to generate a list of completions using:

```
deno completions elvish
```

It goes on to say we should send this output into an "appropriate file". It offers examples for bash, Powershell, & zsh, but not for Elvish. How can I determine the "appropriate file" to send this stdout to?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Charles Duffy. This worked:

```
deno completions elvish > ~/.elvish/rc.elv
```